# create a multi dimensional array from csv

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have a csv file with data shown in the picture.What i want to do is,read the csv file and make a multidimensional array given below

```
Array(
     array(
           [ZAIN BUSINESS EMPIRE PVT LTD]=>['10684054','10686738','10686688','10684062']

          ),

     );
```

I have read the csv and stored the name of companies and ids in separate arrays.

```
  $file_name=$_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
  $csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file($file_name,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
  $keys = array_shift($csv);
   foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) 
     {
     $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
     }
     foreach ($csv as $data)
     {
       $company_id_arr[]=$data['Customer_ID'];
       $name[]=$data['STANDARD NAME IN M2M DB'];
     }
```

[image]

Comment: add your sample csv data with this code

Comment: @Priyank sir uploaded

Comment: why only `['10684054','10686738','10686688','10684062']`? what about other id's.Also what's the column-name for these entries?

Comment: Why have the extra `Array()` around it all? Or in other words, I don't understand the result you want. It's unclear.

Comment: what is the name of third column ( column C) ?

Comment: @Priyank third column name is STANDARD NAME IN M2M DB

Comment: @MuhammadTalha i have added answer.

Comment: thanxk @Priyank

Comment: welcome @MuhammadTalha , Will you please upvote my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<?php
$file_name=$_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file($file_name,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
$keys = array_shift($csv);
 foreach ($csv as $i=>$row) {
    $csv[$i] = array_combine($keys, $row);
   }
   foreach ($csv as $data){
 $company_id_arr[$data['STANDARD NAME IN M2M DB']][]=$data['Customer_ID'];
    //$name[]=$data['STANDARD NAME IN M2M DB'];

    
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
// your result array
$result = [];
foreach ($csv as $data)
{
    // check if your key not exists in $result
    if (empty($result[$data['STANDARD NAME IN M2M DB']])) {
        $result[$data['STANDARD NAME IN M2M DB']] = [];
    }

    // Add value under required key
    $result[$data['STANDARD NAME IN M2M DB']][] = $data['Customer_ID'];
}
```